# How to get button clicked event in ViewCellRenderer Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am creating a Custom `ViewCell` which contains a button, I need a click event in my `ContentPage`

Comment: You can handle tap gesture on Viewcell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the button inside the viewcell is not exposed, so you can create public event inside the `viewcell` for the button click event ,and invoke it when clicking the button.

### Complete Code

*CustomViewCell:*

```
public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ClickEventHandler ClickEvent;

void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ClickEvent(this, args);
}
```

*ContentPage:*

```
//.xmal
<ListView x:Name="listView"  RowHeight="50">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomViewCell ClickEvent="ButtonClick"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

//.cs    
void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    CustomViewCell cell = sender as CustomViewCell;
    object context = cell.BindingContext;//here you can get index or something else
}
```

Comment: I am also using custom ViewCellRenderer I am not sure how can I use in CustomAndroidCell.cs

Comment: Not ViewCellRenderer , all the code are placed in PCL , it works for ios and android.

Comment: it is not working, I am having 2 buttons in one cell may be that would be the issue?

Comment: What's the exact meaning of `it is not working`? , Can you get the value of CustomViewCell ?

Comment: I have added a breakpoint on `ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)`. when I click on the button it doesn't stop here.

Comment: Have you triggered `ClickEvent` in all buttons click event(you said the cell has 2 buttons)?

Comment: Xia -MSFT How can I trigger that?

Comment: call `ClickEvent(this, args);`  inside all buttons click event.

Comment: Hi,@Suyash , i have created sample for you .link: https://github.com/ColeXm/ButtonClickDemo

Comment: yes I have changed my implementation in this way. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

In the xaml code for the button, add the Clicked event:
    Clicked="ButtonClicked"

Then add the method in the .xaml.cs class

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: But the button is in Viewcell and I need the object based on the cell index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event linked to the item in the list, you will want to bind a [Command](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/).

The XAML:

```
<Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" />
```

And, Assuming you're attaching the ViewCell to a ListView, the following should be added to the class that the ItemSource is bound to:

```
public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(ButtonClicked);
    }
}

public ButtonClicked()
{
    //Handle the button click logic here
}
```